# MSI GT60 laptop stuck in endless BIOS Setup loop

Tags: windows-installer, setup, infinite-loop

My MSI GT60 gaming laptop is doing something very weird. I turned it off to relocate it on top of a 25U server rack and when I turned it on the Aptio setup screen appeared. No matter what I do, it comes back to that. It does see the drives because it can identify them, and it sees all other devices, but I can't even get a USB stick with Ubuntu to boot (the computer is running 18.04). I have changed everything that might be even remotely related to this in the setup and nothing helps. I made the USB mode hard disk, I tried Legacy, UEFI and UEFI with CSM in the boot mode select, tried choosing different boot devices, but nothing works. I made a boot USB stick with 18.04 with UNetbootin and it doesn't recognize it in UEFI or Legacy boot mode. Same with the SSD's. I also tried it with secure boot mode off and on and nothing. Only pressing the Del key at boot has any effect. I also tried removing the battery, pressing the power key for 30 seconds and hoping whatever was the problem would get unstuck, but nothing.

What could possibly be going on here?

Comment: Find out the BIOS Function Key. Turn it off.  Start it. Press the Function Key repeatedly to get into BIOS.  Once in, reset BIOS to defaults, Save, Exit and then see if it restarts normally.

Comment: I already did that. Did not help.

Comment: I think that means your drive may be out out commission.

Comment: I find that doubtful, because that would not explain why a bootable USB stick will not work either.

Comment: That is possible. It could also be a motherboard issue. I think you have a hardware problem as all of thing you tried eliminate software altogether.

Comment: I am tempted to agree, but that also would not explain why the laptop always goes back to the BIOS setup screen. I've never seen this in 40 years in IT. If it had a problem accessing the drives it should tell me that, rather than unceremoniously dumping be back to the setup screen. I've seen plenty of mention of this on the web but none of the proposed solutions has helped me. :( At this point I'm thinking something has come loose and I should open up the bottom and check to see all connections are properly seated.

Comment: Have you tried moving it. temporarily, back to its previous location? It's *possible*, though unlikely, that there are very high magnetic fields from a mains transformer in its new rack location, inducing currents into the circuits.

Comment: Heh, that was a good one. Yes, I did try that. Warped minds think alike? :)

Comment: We use laptops in our various server rooms without issue. It was a good thought but it still looks to be a hardware issue.

Comment: Well, the bootable ssd had slipped out of the SATA plug. But I secured it and tried booting again and it still doesn't boot. Bootable USB sticks are not working either.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to strip this thing of anything of value and put it out of its misery...

Comment: I tracked it down. Root cause? Operator stupidity. I accidentally deleted the small boot partition (Ubuntu 18.04) and hadn't noticed until I tried to reboot Anybody know how to reinstate the boot partition?